# Are any of Stephen King's works not connected to The Dark Tower?

Tags: stephen-king, the-dark-tower

Its pretty well known in Stephen King fandom that most if not all of his works are [connected through The Dark Tower series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiverse_(Stephen_King)). But I'm curious if there are any of Stephen King's works which are **explicitly** not connected to The Dark Tower?

EDIT: Updated question to only ask for explicit examples that are not connected since there are many stories that it is unknown.

Comment: King has written literally [hundreds of stories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephen_King_short_fiction_bibliography), the overwhelming majority of which bear zero obvious connection to the Dark Tower series of books'; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephen_King_bibliography

Comment: Obvious might be the word though

Comment: Without defining what "connected" is supposed to mean here, the question doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @Mithoron I updated the question to link to the wikipedia entry for the Stephen King Multiverse. As I did originally mention "its pretty well known", I suppose I figured that anyone unfamiliar with the concept of the Stephen King Multiverse wouldn't have a prayer of answering the question.

Comment: Hmm, so "character are supposed to exist in same multiverse" it is? That's tenuous, but OK...

Comment: @Mithoron its a little bit more complex than that. I don't know that I could explain exactly why though in less than 600 characters. If it interests you I highly suggest you read the novels. Its really kind of ingenious how SK was able to build a mythology that connects all of his works together.

Comment: :/ I read The Dark Tower and know how it works, but in such question like this I'd prefer significant narrative connections, but if you're OK with the answer, then so be it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

All King's writings are at least tenuously connected to *The Dark Tower* multiverse.  The reason (which may, unfortunately, seem overly glib) is that the real world is one of the worlds that *The Dark Tower* cosmology touches. King himself is a character in the story, and real world events (most notably when he was [hit by a minivan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephen_King#Car_accident_and_after_effects)) are part of the narrative structure.  Therefore, at a minimum, everything that Stephen King has ever written exists, in-multiverse, as writings.

Comment: This is a very good point!

Comment: And now my head hurts...

Comment: @ZeissIkon But not as much as it would after being hit by a minivan.

Comment: He also decided to introduce characters from other stores into the Dark Tower. So, it's not even that certain books were connected to the Dark Tower when they were written but he decided to connect the dark tower to them.

e.g. Dinky Earnshaw, Ted Brautigan, Father Callahan.

Comment: (1) Isn't your "_everything that Stephen King has ever written exists, in-multiverse, as writings_" a little bit to out-of-cannon? I think OP is asking about direct in-cannon, in-story connections that can be i.e. marked with a corresponding cite. (2) Are you really sure that King put any connection to The Dark Tower in the book or story written i.e. 20 years before TDT? Anyway, I have a question ([here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/246621/7885)) that has four (if not five) Kings' title that are not connected to the Dark Tower serie or that such connection is not given by a proper cite.