# Connections to "The Dark Tower" in "Carrie", "Misery", "The Tommyknockers" and in "The Green Mile"

Tags: stephen-king, the-dark-tower, the-green-mile

Both the [English Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dark_Tower_(series)) and [its Polish counter-part](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mroczna_Wie%C5%BCa?wprov=sfla1) list following of Stephen King books as supposedly having a  connection to *The Dark Tower* series:

- [Carrie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrie_(novel))
- [Misery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Misery_(novel))
- [The Tommyknockers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tommyknockers) and
- [The Green Mile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Green_Mile_(novel))

Based on the following sources:

- [Dark Tower references in other works of Stephen King or vice versa](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/131740/dark-tower-references-in-other-works-of-stephen-king-or-vice-versa)
- [Are any of Stephen King's works not connected to The Dark Tower?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/196807/31394)
- [Reading order/reading plan for the wider Dark Tower universe?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/153445/31394)
- [Nineteen Books With Dark Tower Connections](https://www.bustle.com/articles/172878-19-books-with-dark-tower-connections-you-didnt-know-about)
- My own detailed reading of these books

I have found **zero** (none) connection to *The Dark Tower* series in any of the listed books.

Can someone explain (by giving some examples or cites) how exactly the above books are connected to Stephen King's most recognisable book series?

**EDIT**: *I have*:

- *Read all mentioned books at a fairly deep level of detail*
- *Not read anything from *The Dark Tower* serie (except some short)*

*Thus, for me "a connection" is bi-directional or rather "either way". If in *The Dark Tower* it is revealed that "lady from Misery" reappeared as a Gunslinger's Aunt then I am perfectly fine with that.*

Comment: The German Wikipedia article mentions a connection in tommyknockers. Apparently there is a boy who disappears during a magic trick in tommyknockers and who appears in the dark tower. Not knowing tommyknockers and beibgnobly superficially familiar with the dark tower I can’t judge the accuracy of this though.

Comment: https://stephenking.com/darktower/connections/submitted_connections.html has some user-submitted connections which, admittedly, feel a bit iffy to me.

Comment: Isn't it the other way around? The connections are found in The Dark Tower, not in the other books.

Comment: @Philipp Score, base and save! :) Or whatever they yell in American Baseball. One down, three to come. Thanks!

Comment: @FuzzyBoots If you are not convinced then I am not convinced (citing "Jurassic Park" this time)! :)

Comment: @JK. Explained in the question, but totally agree.